# How to create a account with Email And Password method after Verifying Phone with PhoneAuthProvider?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a kind of shopping Android app and at the time of creating new user account i want to verify the user with his Phone number and want to log in the user by there email.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(users.getPhoneNumber(), 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Otp_Activity.this,
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull @NotNull String s, @NonNull @NotNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    otpID = s;
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, "Otp sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull @NotNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull @NotNull FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    firebaseAuth = SplashScreen.firebaseAuthForPhone;
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        createAccountWithEmail(userEmail, userPassword);


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}

public void createAccountWithEmail(String email, String passWord)
{
    firebaseAuthForEmail.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passWord)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, "Email Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));


                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Otp_Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


}
```

Why i cant logout with the account created with email?

do PhoneAuthProvider logs in after verifying account? if yes is there any way to stop it?

Comment: You're make the easier implementation more complex. If you want your user to login with email/phone first create the user with phone login after that update user email and ask him to create a password. Now in your login specify user to use the login method and check if user has an password set and login with that. Simple!

Comment: I'll try posting the answer with code if you are not sure what process I'm trying to explain.

Comment: If you want to logout your user use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().Sign out();`

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().Sign out();  i am using that but thanks for your help

Comment: **do PhoneAuthProvider logs in after verifying account? if yes is there any way to stop it?** It's a yes or no answer in your code you're performing the create user operation after the phone login is complete! Phone Auth verify the phone numbers and logs in the user.

Comment: How do i logout of PhoneAuthProvider on onVerifiation()

Comment: can you please explain why you want to logout and create another login/registration. If you do that you create another user from the same device. which gives two different user ID's from one device.

Comment: Why do you need to create another account with an email after you already create the account with the phone number?

Comment: When you implemented authentication processes, you have to use one specific way for each user.  For Example- If a user needs to create an account with a phone number, need to implement that process for that kind of user. if the user needs to create an account with email, need to implement that process for that kind of user.  Implementing the both way for one user is not a recommended way.

Comment: I want user to login with there email and password instead of there phonenumber because firebase have a limited otp .

Comment: I want to logout of the PhoneAuthProvider because when user logout of the main app he only logs out of the email account and and when he reopens the app after logout he directly go to MainActivity because PhoneAuthProvider is not logged out

Comment: @RishiKumar, then remove the phone number authentication process and use email-based authentication for the user authentication process. use only one specific way for authentication process like email and password authentication process. then your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one specific authentication process for each user. If you need to authenticate the user with the email and password, follow [this process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth).

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// Initialize Firebase Auth
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then create account with email and password.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    
                    // add the logic
                } else {
                    // add the logic
                }
            }
        });
```

After account creating process, you could use this process for the sign in process.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // add the logic
                } else {
                    // add the logic
                }
            }
        });
```

And you could use this method for sign out the user.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```